# Do I need to use and assignment with a lock?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, linq

This is possibly a silly question, but do I need to use and assignment with a lock, or can I simply return the results.

For example:

I have a private helper method that returns an IEnumerable list of file names. It uses a lock to ensure the method is thread safe while it is iterating around the m_transfers collection.

Do I need an assignment...

```
IEnumerable<String> updated;
lock (m_transfers.Lock)
{
    updated = m_transfers.Values.Where(transfer => transfer.Updated)
                         .Select(transfer => transfer.Filename);
}
return updated;
```

Or can I just do

```
lock (m_transfers.Lock)
{
    return updated = m_transfers.Values.Where(transfer => transfer.Updated)
                            .Select(transfer => transfer.Filename);
}
```

Comment: More important: Is all other access to `m_transfers.Values` also being guarded? It looks like you might not need a `lock()` at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to add an extra variable; the semantic is the same either way, since in either case we only *actually* return the value once we have relinquished the lock.

Since the variable doesn't serve a purpose, I would remove it and use the second version - although *technically*, the compiler actually puts it back in anyway (a `lock` involves a `try`/`finally`, and at the IL level you can't `ret` from inside a `try`; so the *compiler* actually writes it like your first version).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Great help.

Answer (score 1):

Same as you don't have to do this in case of `try`, `using`, you don't have to do this here. Compiler puts needed bits of code for you on function exit.

Check this for more info: [Monitor vs lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978850/monitor-vs-lock)

Answer (score 0):

both are valid. 
as soon as you return execution comes out of the block.