# C# thread accesed to if block, whose condition returns false

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, conditional-statements

This block of code is being accessed by many threads

```
    // All code is from same class

    public void ExecuteCommand(IAsciiCommand command, IAsciiCommandSynchronousResponder responder)
    {
        lock (commander)
        {
            if (commander.IsConnected)
            {
                commander.ExecuteCommand(command, responder);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        var tmp = commander.IsConnected;
        commander.Disconnect();
        if (commander.IsConnected != tmp && !commander.IsConnected)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("IsConnected");
        }
    }
```

And eventually i get this: [image: Error]

How is this possible, that thread accessed into if statement, whose condition returns false? How can i fix it?

Comment: Where do you close this "port"? Is that code also being locked?

Comment: Service(has connection and port) <--> Model <--> GUI

Comment: @Groo I'm pretty basic at c# , What's a monitor?

Comment: But where do you close it? Is there a method which closes this port, without taking a lock? What type of a port is this anyway? **(edit)** Monitor is the synchronization construct [used by the lock statement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4978886/69809). My question was basically "do you lock while closing".

Comment: See the updated source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the check and the call lack *atomicity*. Here is a sequence of events that could lead to an exception:

- Two threads, A and B, are reaching the condition at the same time
- Thread A checks the condition, which returns `true`, so it enters the `if` block
- At the same time, thread scheduler decides that thread A has exhausted its time slot, and suspends it
- Thread B calls `Disconnect`
- Thread scheduler resumes thread A, which is inside the `if` condition. However, the command is no longer connected
- This causes the exception

You can fix it by locking `commander` inside `Disconnect()`.

```
public void Disconnect()
{
    bool doEvent;
    lock(commander) {
        var tmp = commander.IsConnected;
        commander.Disconnect();
        doEvent = (commander.IsConnected != tmp && !commander.IsConnected)
    }
    // Run OnPropertyChanged outside the locked context 
    if (doEvent)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("IsConnected");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to lock on a static object.  Right now you're creating separate locks based on the object your are working with (`commander`).  Try this:

```
public class WhatEverClassHasTheExecuteCommandMethod
{
     private static object _lock = new object();

     public void ExecuteCommand(IAsciiCommand command, IAsciiCommandSynchronousResponder responder)
     {
          lock (_lock)
              if (commander.IsConnected)                  
                 commander.ExecuteCommand(command, responder);
     }
}
```

Comment: I don't think OP has multiple `commander` instances. And if s/he does, I don't see why you would need to lock access to all of them if you are writing to a single one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not locking while disconnecting, it's entirely possible to get a race condition. The basic solution is to add a lock inside the `Disconnect` method:

```
public void Disconnect()
{
    lock (commander)
    {
        var tmp = commander.IsConnected;
        commander.Disconnect();
        if (commander.IsConnected != tmp && !commander.IsConnected)
            OnPropertyChanged("IsConnected");
    }
}
```