# How to properly unsubscribe to an event

Tags: c#

How can I properly unsubscribe to an event and be sure that the called method is not called now ?

My problem is with this kind of code :

```
public class MyClassWithEvent
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;
    public int Field;
}

public class MyMainClass
{
    private MyClassWithEvent myClass;

    public void Start()
    {
        myClass.MyEvent += new EventHandler(doSomething);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        myClass.MyEvent -= new EventHandler(doSomething);
        myClass = null;
    }

    private void doSomething()
    {
        myClass.Field = 42;
    }
}
```

If `myClass = null` is called while `doSomething` is executing, instruction `myClass.Field = 42` raise an error because myClass is null.

How can I be sure that `doSomething` is not executing before setting `myClass = null` ?

**Edit:**

Other example:

```
public void Stop()
{
    myClass.MyEvent -= new EventHandler(doSomething);

    // Can I add a function here to be sure that doSomething is not running ?

    myClass.Field = 101;
}
```

In that case, I will not be sure if `myClass.Field` is 42 or 101.

**Edit2:**

Apparently my question is not as simple as I thought. I will explain my precise case.

My code is :

```
public class MyMainClass
{
    object camera;//can be type uEye.Camera or DirectShowCamera
    bool isRunning = false;

    public void Start()
    {
        if (camera is uEye.Camera)
        {
            camera.EventFrame += new EventHandler(NewFrameArrived);
        }
        else if (camera is DirectShowCamera)
        {
            //other init
        }
        isRunning = true;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (camera is uEye.Camera)
        {
            camera.EventFrame -= new EventHandler(NewFrameArrived);
            camera.exit;
        }
        else if (camera is DirectShowCamera)
        {
            //other stop
        }
        isRunning = false;
    }

    public void ChangeCamera(object new camera)
    {
        if (isRunning)
            Stop()
        camera = new camera();
    }

    void NewFrameArrived(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        uEye.Camera Camera = sender as uEye.Camera;
        Int32 s32MemID;
        Camera.Memory.GetActive(out s32MemID);

        lock (_frameCameralocker)
        {
            if (_frameCamera != null)
                _frameCamera.Dispose();
            _frameCamera = null;
            Camera.Memory.ToBitmap(s32MemID, out _frameCamera);
        }

        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            lock (_frameCameralocker)
            {
                var bitmapData = _frameCamera.LockBits(
                    new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, _frameCamera.Width, _frameCamera.Height),
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, _frameCamera.PixelFormat);

                if (_frameCamera.PixelFormat == System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed)
                {
                    DeviceSource = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.Create(
                                                        bitmapData.Width, bitmapData.Height, 96, 96, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Gray8, null,
                                                        bitmapData.Scan0, bitmapData.Stride * bitmapData.Height, bitmapData.Stride);
                }

                _frameCamera.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

                if (OnNewBitmapReady != null)
                    OnNewBitmapReady(this, null);
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

And when I change the camera from uEye to directshow sometime I have a AccessViolationException in `DeviceSource = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.Create` (method `NewFrameArrived`) because I try to create BitmapSource from an exited camera

Comment: Check if it's null before assigning the value?

Comment: My example is maybe too simple, I can have other case without using `myClass`. I will edit my question to show other case.

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne just checking doesnt solve a problem, because myClass can be assigned to null after checking and before using. Thats why I suggest to keep reference to myClass in local value.

Comment: You haven't shown the code that is raising the event or where/why this happens. Unless this is an asynchronous or parallel part of the program, the event should never be raised inbetween your statements. This means that the raising of the event in the first piece of code should either happen before `Stop`, or afterwards it would not call `doSomething`. In your last example, the event should not be raised until some later piece of code executes, *after* `Field` has been set to 101.

Comment: I've try to simplify my code to be clear, I thought that the problem was simple, apparently not. maybe a third edit will help.

Comment: You have to use the `lock` keyword in code where threads both read and write a variable.   Forgetting to do so is a very basic threading race bug and causes random failure.

Comment: I have a `lock` the problem seems to come from the `Invoke` and the read from memory.

Comment: @A.Pissicat - The updated code doesn't compile. It's missing a lot of code and it has many syntax errors. If you really want some good help you should provide a [mcve].

Comment: @A.Pissicat - What happens if you put `lock (_frameCameralocker)` into the `Start` and `Stop` methods?

Comment: It seems to work :-) The exception don't raise all the time, but I don't see it since I locked the Stop. Thank you

Comment: @A.Pissicat you could still run in to a problem where the dispatcher was queued before the `Stop()` lock happened. You just need to put a `IsRunning` check in the dispatcher, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your updated question, the only thing you need to do is just lock the `Stop()` action from the same lock as the `Dispatcher.Invoke`

```
public void Stop()
{
    lock(_frameCameralocker)
    {
        if (camera is uEye.Camera)
        {
            camera.EventFrame -= new EventHandler(NewFrameArrived);
            camera.exit;
        }
        else if (camera is DirectShowCamera)
        {
            //other stop
        }
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

This will make sure all `NewFrameArrived` calls finished or have not started before you create the new camera. Then inside the dispatcher check to see if you are running or not just in case a frame was queued before a `Stop()` call was started and completed.

```
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        lock (_frameCameralocker)
        {
            if(!isRunning)
                return;

            var bitmapData = _frameCamera.LockBits(
                new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, _frameCamera.Width, _frameCamera.Height),
                System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, _frameCamera.PixelFormat);

            if (_frameCamera.PixelFormat == System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed)
            {
                DeviceSource = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.Create(
                                                    bitmapData.Width, bitmapData.Height, 96, 96, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Gray8, null,
                                                    bitmapData.Scan0, bitmapData.Stride * bitmapData.Height, bitmapData.Stride);
            }

            _frameCamera.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

            if (OnNewBitmapReady != null)
                OnNewBitmapReady(this, null);
        }
    }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a good use for [Monitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

The idea is that you use a lock to make sure you are not using the same resource twice at the (almost) same time :

```
public class MyClassWithEvent
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;
    public int Field;
}

public class MyMainClass
{
    private MyClassWithEvent myClass;
    private object mylock;

    public void Start()
    {
        myClass.MyEvent += new EventHandler(doSomething);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        myClass.MyEvent -= new EventHandler(doSomething);
        Monitor.Enter(mylock); //If somebody else already took the lock, we will wait here
        myClass = null;
        Monitor.Exit(mylock); //We release the lock, so others can access it
    }

    private void doSomething()
    {
        Monitor.Enter(mylock);
        if myClass != null
        {
            myClass.Field = 42;
        }
        Monitor.Exit(mylock);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

According to comments, [Lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) would be a better use ([actually a short-hand for Monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978850/monitor-vs-lock)) :

```
public class MyClassWithEvent
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;
    public int Field;
}

public class MyMainClass
{
    private MyClassWithEvent myClass;
    private object mylock;

    public void Start()
    {
        myClass.MyEvent += new EventHandler(doSomething);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        myClass.MyEvent -= new EventHandler(doSomething);
        lock (mylock) //If somebody else already took the lock, we will wait here
        {
            myClass = null;
        } //We release the lock, so others can access it
    }

    private void doSomething()
    {
        lock(mylock)
        {
            if myClass != null
            {
                myClass.Field = 42;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to use `Monitor` just use `lock`.

Comment: use lock or try finally block for locking an object.

Comment: I used my own lock (see edit2) instead of `Monitor`, I did not have the Exception now

Answer (score 0):

Instead

```
myClass.Field = 42;
```

Do

```
val local = myClass;
if (local != null)
    local.Field = 42;
```

Comment: I edited my question with another case, your solution will not work with the second case. I'm searching for a synchronization mechanism

Comment: In that case take a look at ```ReaderWriterLockSlim``` I think it can be useful for you, because you are trying to control write operations.  MSDN link  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx