# When would it make sense to use a semaphore with a maxCount of 1?

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore

From what I'm reading, semaphores are designed to allow multiple threads to access a pool of resources at the same time. I'm also reading that mutexes only allow a single thread to access a resource a time. I'm currently working with some code that uses a `SemaphoreSlim` to ensure that only one thread can access a resource.

Would it ever make sense to create a semaphore, where only a single thread can access the pool of resources at once? In that case, why not use a `Mutex`? Or (from what I'm reading) a similar construct in C# - a `lock` or a `Monitor`? It sounds like mutexes/locks/monitors are simpler, and less potentially-misleading.

Comment: `SemaphoreSlim` is waaay faster than `Mutex`, [rtfm](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Locking).

Comment: You would want to use `Monitor` most of times, but it has a limitation I can't remember right now, something with leaving in another thread. `SemaphoreSlim` doesn't have it.

Comment: @Sinatr isn't `Monitor` just `lock`?

Comment: @FCin, `lock` [is implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4978936/1997232) using `Monitor`.

Comment: @Sinatr that is what I'm saying. `lock` is syntactic sugar for `Monitor`.

Comment: @Sinatr lock is compiled into a try/finally that _uses_ Monitor to achieve its functionality, it’s not “syntactic sugar for monitor”

Comment: @ScottPerham The point I'm trying to make is that someone might think that using `Monitor` might be something new and rare when in reality it is created every time some uses `lock`.

Answer (score 1):

If single thread is granted an exclusive access to the resource, I don't see a reason why not use `Mutex` or any other type meant for exclusive lock.

> It sounds like mutexes/locks/monitors are simpler, and less
>   potentially-misleading.

Can't argue with that, in this case.

Comment: `Monitor` locking is 50 times faster than `Mutex`. A good reason to not use mutexes.